# Python Dictionary key and structure question

Tags: python, dictionary, key

New to Python looking to the pros for help.  I am building a python program that compares two text databases. I have broken the individual tables into dictionaries and now I am trying to decide what items in the table to be part of the highest level of the key so I can filter easily, minimize run time, loops etc.  Here is my starting structure but I am not sold on it.

```
pfcompare.Buses1

{'10000"Bus Name 1"46.0000': {'name': 'Bus Name 1', 'kv': 46.0, 'index': 2671, 'type': 1, 'vsched': 1.0, 'area': 10, 'zone': 105, 'vmax': 1.05, 'vmin': 0.95, 'owner': 129, 'subnumber': -1, 'subname': '" "', 'BA': 27}}
```

So would it bet better to change this to say this:

```
{'10000"Bus Name 1"46.0000', 10, 105: {'name': 'Bus Name 1', 'kv': 46.0, 'index': 2671, 'type': 1, 'vsched': 1.0, 'area': 10, 'zone': 105, 'vmax': 1.05, 'vmin': 0.95, 'owner': 129, 'subnumber': -1, 'subname': '" "', 'BA': 27}}
```

Where if I plan to filter on Area and Zone (in this example area = 10 and zone = 105) in the highest level of keys would this speed sorting or filtering of entries?  I ask because It appears to me that the way I have it now I would have to have a loop through '10000"Bus Name 1"46.0000' keys to see if it is area 10 zone 105?  Correct or am I missing something.  All help will be appreciated. I just feel structure could make my life easy in this program or miserable!  Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you want a tuple as key, use parentheses:

```
{('10000"Bus Name 1"46.0000', 10, 105): {...}}
```

Second, you hesitate to put some informations in the main key, like above, to avoid a loop on the inner keys. But that's not how dictionaries are implemented. In most languages, dictionaries are [hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). There are many implementations, but the main principle is:

- use a function that maps the keys to an int (the `hash`)
- store the pairs `key, value` in an array, at an index depending on `hash` (e.g. `hash % len(array)`)
- find a way to resolve collisions (different keys having the same `hash`)

Usually, there are few collisions, thus the lookup is done in constant time (amortized `O(1)`) and does not need a loop (`O(n)` where `n` is the number of `key, value` pairs). *Basically, it is fast and does not depend on the size of the dict.*

The conclusion is that your optimization is probably not a good idea (I'm cautious because it depends on complex factors, but I'm pretty sure this won't be the bottleneck of your program).

---

You have another issue: how do you find the data corresponding to `'10000"Bus Name 1"46.0000'` if you don't know the area and zone? And if you don't need a direct lookup, just use a list of one level dicts and forget the two levels dict:

```
[{id: '10000"Bus Name 1"46.0000', 'name': 'Bus Name 1', 'kv': 46.0, ... }, {id: ... }, {id: ... }]
```

If you need to find data by `id` or by area or by zone, you could create auxiliary dicts to map `zone -> set of id having that zone` or `area -> set of id having that area`.

---

And if you need to select data on specific key/value combinations, sort, agggreate, ...,  maybe you should have a look at [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) or a database like [sqlite](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html)